# Symfony2 : Change {{ form_enctype }} to {{ form_start }} with a custom path

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm working on updating my code to Symfony3 standards but I come to some problems with some of my forms. I tried several things but nothing is working.

In my twig :

```
<form action="{{ path('paces_colle_gestioncsv_imprimer', 
{ 'id' : document.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
</form>
```

{{ form_enctype }} is deprecated since Symfony 2.8. I have to get the path to the controller to change it to {{ form_start }}

In my controller :

```
public function ajouterErrataAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $document = $em->getRepository('PACESColleBundle:DocumentCSV')->find($id);
    if(!$document){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Document inexistant');
    }
    $colle = $document->getColle();

    $form = $this->createForm(ajouterErrataType::class);

    return $this->render('PACESColleBundle:Classement:ajouterErrata.html.twig', array(
        "colle" => $colle,
        "document" => $document,
        "form" => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

My formType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('errata', TextareaType::class, array('required' => false,
                                          'attr' => array('class'=>'ckeditor')
        ))

        ->add('precision', TextareaType::class, array('required' => false,
                                             'attr' => array('class'=>'ckeditor')))

        ->add('submit',SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Imprimer'));
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the action path like this:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(ajouterErrataType::class, $data, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl(''paces_colle_gestioncsv_imprimer', ['id' => $document->getId()]),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override action in controller or template:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form
Have you tried?

Comment: I've already tried this but action is not rendered. 

Controller :

`$form = $this->createForm(ajouterErrataType::class, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('paces_colle_gestioncsv_imprimer', array('id' => $document->getId())),
            'method' => 'POST'
        ));`

Comment: Second argument of createForm method is data which is binded to form. Use third argument:
`$this->createForm(ajouterErrataType::class, _[entity or array]_, **( 'action' => $this->generateUrl('paces_colle_gestioncsv_imprimer', array('id' => $document->getId())), 'method' => 'POST' ))**);`

or try in template:
`{{ form_start(form, {'action': path([generate your route]), 'method': 'POST' }) }}`

Comment: Sorry for the delay : I was occupied with something else.

I had a hard time figuring out that my entity for this form was null.

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony 3 way of doing it is like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html):

```
$form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('target_route'),
    'method' => 'GET',
));
```